# How do I enable scrolling in the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code 1.41.1 on Manjaro. I can't scroll in the integrated terminal with the scroll wheel on my mouse nor using two fingers on my trackpad. I have to navigate my cursor to the scroll bar on the right side of the terminal to be able to scroll at all. How do I enable scrolling with my mouse's scroll wheel or my trackpad?